# AddSource prints details form logger file itself and doesn't print real caller's details

Tags: go

I have written a logger wrapper over slog in go.

```
package logger

import (
    "sync"

    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"

    "golang.org/x/exp/slog" 
)

type SlogLogger struct {
    *slog.Logger
    logFile *lumberjack.Logger
}

var factory = &LoggerFactory{
    loggers: make(map[string]*SlogLogger),
}

type LoggerFactory struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    loggers map[string]*SlogLogger
}

type LoggerConfig struct {
    LogFilePath string
    LogFormat   string
}

// TODO: Read all the values from config
func NewDefaultLogger() *SlogLogger {
    logFilePath := "./cs_runner.log"
    factory.mu.Lock()
    defer factory.mu.Unlock()

    // Check if a logger instance for this log file already exists
    if logger, ok := factory.loggers[logFilePath]; ok {
        return logger
    }
    lumberjack := &lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   logFilePath,
        MaxSize:    1, // megabytes
        MaxBackups: 5,
        MaxAge:     28,   //days
        Compress:   true, // disabled by default
    }
    l := slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(lumberjack, &slog.HandlerOptions{
        Level:     slog.LevelDebug,
        AddSource: true,
    }))
    logger := &SlogLogger{l, lumberjack}
    factory.loggers[logFilePath] = logger
    return logger
}

func (l *SlogLogger) Close() {
    // TODO: Check for any other cleanup activities
    l.logFile.Close()
}
func (l *SlogLogger) Debugf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Info(format, args...)
}
func (l *SlogLogger) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Info(format, args...)
}
func (l *SlogLogger) Errorf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Error(format, args...)
}
```

But this prints the source details from the logger file `slog_logger.go`, not its real caller details:

```
time=2023-08-27T10:41:36.805+05:30 level=INFO source=/home/user1/myproject/logging/slog_logger.go:95 msg="This is a Debug log message"
```

I tried to read through and understood that there is 'logDepth' option to set the level of caller depth, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with

```
func (l *SlogLogger) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    var pcs [1]uintptr
    runtime.Callers(2, pcs[:]) // skip [Callers, Infof]
    r := slog.NewRecord(time.Now(), slog.LevelInfo, fmt.Sprintf(format, args...), pcs[0])
    _ = l.Handler().Handle(context.Background(), r)
}
```